# Wait for a given time in Java

Tags: java

I just wonder if there is a way to wait(sec). I measure memory in java and then I call garbage collection and after some time I want to measure the memory again. I thought about quartz but is in it too complicated, I heard thread.sleep is not accurate..

Thanx

Comment: What is the amount of time (in orders of magnitude) you want to wait and how accurate should it be?

Comment: Calling GC has no effect. GC will be handled by JVM when required. If memory is not being free after GC that means your code has some memory leak.

Comment: And btw: You are looking for a sophisticated way that isn't too complicated? ^^

Comment: Calling GC *may* have no effect, noting that at least one major implementation calling it *does* have an effect.

Comment: I also sweep the db, and I just want to run a function, which will measure the heap before and after gc and db sweep.

Comment: The question was in regards to accurate timing, not whether or not GC would have any effect. See my answer below for an accurate solution.

Answer (score 2):

See [sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html).

`Thread.sleep` causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period. This is an efficient means of making processor time available to the other threads of an application or other applications that might be running on a computer system.

Comment: *"However, these sleep times are not guaranteed to be precise, because they are limited by the facilities provided by the underlying OS. Also, the sleep period can be terminated by interrupts, as we'll see in a later section. In any case, you cannot assume that invoking sleep will suspend the thread for precisely the time period specified."* (from your link)

Comment: Not to mention that Thread.Sleep() is buggy as heck on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something a little more accurate you can use nanoTime.

```
   public static void sleepNanos (long nanoDuration) throws InterruptedException {
        final long end = System.nanoTime() + nanoDuration;
        long timeLeft = nanoDuration;
        do {
            if (timeLeft > SLEEP_PRECISION)
                Thread.sleep (1);
            else
                if (timeLeft > SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION)
                    Thread.yield();

            timeLeft = end - System.nanoTime();
        } while (timeLeft > 0);
    }
```

Comment: Mind you, there will be some minor CPU cost using this method but it will be accurate to within ~2-3 millis.

Comment: what should be value of `SLEEP_PRECISION` and  `SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION `to test it for `1000NS`

Comment: My SLEEP_PRECISION is at 2ms, SPIN_YIELD_PRECISION at 1000ns.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep(1000);` will sleep for 1 sec. 
But you will not the free any memory as you expect. 
Use some profiler tool like [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) or [yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/) to do the GC. If you are using Netbeans it has builtin profiler.